# Why is it so hard to install SVN in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse, subversive, polarion

I've been using eclipse for some time, and know there are two options in the market place, the SVN eclipse sponsored connector and then subversvion.tigris.org, my problem is getting connectors to actually install and work, when installing native Java I get errors, I have a hard time getting polarion connectors to work, in my current case the specific error I am getting now is that it cannot initialize apache class subversion.javahl.SVNClient and its frustrating that SVN cannot get installed out of the box with these newer versions of eclipse. Does anyone have this problem? Are other folks having issues getting polarion connectors to work? Just curious if someone has a solution. thanks

Comment: You're not alone.  My understanding is that there is some sort of licensing BS that legally hinders Eclipse from offering a decent svn integration.  I just gave up and stuck w/ NetBeans, which has had seamless svn integration forever.

Comment: Thanks budy, i found this https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/products/svn/subversive/download but trying to install the latest stable release is not stable at all, so I guess I will keep looking. Hate to migrate 200 plugins to GIT :)

Comment: Its also hard to find the svn connector install dialog after the initial installation of SVN!

Comment: The reason is simply cause SVN is not used in Eclipse itself cause Eclipse has decided to move to Git a longer time ago. Furthermore many projects have migrated to Git in the meantime so the need for better integration in Eclipse has decreased. My recommendation is to move to Git...Yeah it means work (in Maven projects we have migrated more into more than 100 Git repos...)...I don't see any license issue cause Subversion is Apache project and Eclipse is Eclipse License ?..The issue is simply the interest has reduced. That is open source...

Comment: Eclipse Subversive was part of the [Simultaneous Release until 2017](https://projects.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen). In 2015 Polarion the company which was the main driver of this open source project was acquired by Siemens. Subversive requires a connector to work: either JavaHL (native library + Java API) or SVNKit (100% Java). Since the connector licenses are not EPL-compatible, they not allowed to be shipped as part of Subversive (from eclipse.org) but must be installed separately (from Polarion/Siemens). I'm using Subversive+SVNKit without problems for not-yet-Git projects. @khmarbaise

Comment: Hey gents, i truly appreciate all the comments on this as I now get it, GIT is moving forward SVN is not, its just those git pulls/pushes and local commits take time to get used to, ultimately i will be migrating to GIT and assume I can get a way to import my 8K+ revisions into a git repo with a bit of research. thanks again, this is why I love this site.

Comment: SVN is moving forward but unfortunately not the Eclipse plugins....

Comment: @khmarbaise I think that statement is right on, there are honestly times when its better to have a central repo than going through the hoops and jumps with GIT, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, the latest release of subversion does not install from the market place, i went to the home page for the project on eclipse, downloaded the archive release for luna, installed it into the most recent version of eclipse and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Subclipse, which is in the Marketplace, information on installation is here:

https://github.com/subclipse/subclipse/wiki

Most of the issues are around getting the native Subversion API installed for your OS but there is some information on that page that can help. If you are willing to use the pure Java API there should really not be any difficulty but the native API is better and preferred, especially if you intend to also use the SVN CLI or other SVN clients on the same working copy.

Comment: The Pure Java API gives me a apache.SVNClient failed to initialize when looking at it in the connector drop down, was able to get Luna release to work so I think I'm good for now thanks for posting

Comment: Your other message imply you are using Subversive though.  I was answering for Subclipse.  Also, the apache.SVNClient is the "native" API meaning it needs native DLL or .so/.dylib that is loads. The Pure Java API is SVNKit.